# How do locally generated files work and how do I implement them?

Tags: javascript, node.js, download

How do locally generated files work and how do I implement them on server and client side?

What I mean by "locally generated files" is when you download a file from Google Drive it is fast, really fast on bad networks.

[image: Download from google drive]

But on other sites (like downloading Windows from Microsoft) it utilizes the network to the fullest.

[image: Downloading windows]

To give one more example, look at [fastest fish](https://fastest.fish/test-files). Network files download use the network to their fullest.

[image: Network files from fastest fish]

But what is puzzling is how fast the same file using locally generated option is. It actually finished downloading while I was editing this snip.

Like how cool is that downloading 1 GB in less than 10 seconds?

[image: Locally generated option from fastest fish]

To quote them

> These locally generated files will download much quicker than the network downloaded files since their content's are generated on the fly. Their download speed is restricted only by your device's processor and storage drive speed.

What is puzzling for me is where do they get the extra information on bad networks, like where does it get more information from a `200kbit` stream?

- It isn't file compression
- You can't hardcode it in the HTML as it won't load the page from the servers

### So the main question:

How do I implement this cool feature in a Node.js server and serve it at high speed in bad network connections?

Comment: Under locally-generated files it says *These files are generated locally on your device, these downloads will not accurately reflect your download speed. If you are looking to test your network use the network downloaded test files instead.*  - So you're not actually downloading something from another server.

Comment: Those "locally generated files" appear to be random data. You can generate all the random data you want in JavaScript and then turn it into a data URL, but I don't know what the point would be.

Comment: Ok so I am not downloading anything from another server then where is the data comming from. especially google drive. thats not random data.

Comment: sorry for bad communication skills I know that I am bad at it

Comment: You can't get information faster from a server to your computer than the network connection allows; there's no magic to circumvent this. If the data is random data generated in your browser, obviously there's no need to transfer anything from any server. If the data is actually data from some server, then they probably used clever caching in local storage and/or downloading in the background before you even clicked anything, and then just assemble the final file locally.

Comment: but google drive is doing none of the above, it is not random data, it is a file , and it is also not stored in in local cache as you still have to download the entire file after the cache depletes and also you cant cache everything from your google drive but google drive's speed never takes a dip

Comment: From your screenshot, Google Drive uses about 5 MB/s. That's decent for a modern residential connection. What mystery needs to be answered here? Google's servers are fast, end of story.

Comment: noo I dont live in urban aeras, to the countryside and my bandwith is about 200 KB/s yes a really terrible connectivity for refrence here is a windows iso downloding for 1 whole minute (microsoft's servers are alo fast)  [link](https://imgur.com/a/q7erzFM)